# WebView2 - Convert HTML Tbody To A Collection Using JSON

Tags: json.net, webview2

I have a table in my HTML page that I need to send to the host. I use `ExecuteScriptAsync` method (WebView2) in order to do that. That method returns a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject as a result. and it looks like this `{{ "1": {}, "2": {}, "3": {}, "4": {}, "5": {}, "6": {}, "7": {} }}` . The number of rows is correct but as you can see you don't have a full access to the table.

What is the proper way to deserialize a JObject to get a table

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(await this.WebView2Form.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('" + TABLEID + "')." + rows));
```

In other words, I need to execute the javascript below and be able to read the result in C#

```
document.getElementById("myTable").rows
```

Comment: *What is the proper way to deserialize an HTML table in C# using Newtonsoft?* -- Json.NET is for parsing JSON not HTML, there is no proper way to use Newtonsoft to deserialize an [HTML table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).  Or, maybe you have a JSON array embedded in your HTML that you want to parse with Newtonsoft?  If so, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing the JSON string you are trying to parse -- i.e. the string returned by `await this.WebView2Form.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('" + TABLEID + "')." + rows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, @David Risney explains very well, why you can't serialize a `HTMLCollection` (which what the `rows` property returns) to JSON.

What you can do instead is to write a javascript function that returns a 2 dimensional array, which will automatically be serialized to JSON and easily deserialized back to a 2 dimensional array in C#.

**I assume you want to read the text of all cells as an array.**

Such function is here:

```
var TableContent = function (tableId)
{
    let array = [];

    /** @type {NodeListOf<HTMLTableRowElement>} */
    let rows = document.querySelectorAll('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr');

    rows.forEach(function (row, i, rows)
    {
        array[i] = [];
        Array.from(row.cells).forEach(function (cell, j, cells)
        {
            array[i][j] = cell.textContent;
        });
    });
    return array;
};
```

(You know how to inject javascript into `WebView2`).

Now in C# its quite easy to get an array:

```
string tableId = "GridView1";
string json = await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("TableContent('" + tableId + "')");
string[][] cellsContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(json);
```

Now you have a 2 dimensional string array with all cells text.

You can access it like this:

```
cellsContent[rowIndex][cellIndex]
```

Comment: I created my own javascript function and called it from the host. Your idea worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

ExecuteScriptAsync serializes the result of the script execution into JSON using JSON.stringify. In your browser if you navigate to a page with a table like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table, then open the DevTools and run the following you see the same sort of result:

```
JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("perfCardTable").rows)
```

```
"{\"0\":{},\"1\":{},\"2\":{},\"3\":{},\"4\":{}}"
```

The issue is that JSON.stringify only serializes hasOwnProperty properties directly on the object and not properties prototypically inherited from its parent object. Pretty much every DOM object inherits all of its properties from its parent object so you'll see `{}` as the result of JSON.stringify of any DOM object.

To work around this you can copy properties you care about directly onto a new object.

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(document.getElementById("perfCardTable").rows).map(row => { 
    let copy = {};
    for (let name in row) {
        copy[name] = row[name];
    }
    return copy;
}));
```

The result of this is very large, and just does properties on the row and not properties of those properties, so you probably want to pick out particular properties you're interested in rather than copying everything.

Incidentally, if JSON.stringify did serialize all inherited properties, it would throw if you gave it a table row DOM object because it has an ownerDocument property. The ownerDocument is the containing document which lets you get its children and eventually back to your table row DOM element which is a circular reference not allowed by JSON.stringify.

Comment: Thanks again for the good explanation, David. It helped a lot.
I finally created a javascript function that returns an array based on an HTML table. The function needs to be immediate. I set the script as a parameter for ExecuteScriptAsync and it returned the table for me.